# ASP.NET VB Menus

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, menu

So this seems to be harder to find than it should be. I need to create a menu bar (similar to VB6) for my ASP.NET application.

What I ***don't*** need is a standard navigation menu bar (plenty of those out there). I'm not redirecting to a different page. What i do need is a menubar that will behave similarly to a VB6 menu, or ASP.NET button control. I have to postback and execute some VB code (depending on what menu item the user selected).

Call me dumb, but I can't find Jack out there (or Jill, for that matter). Anybody know of a good resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the `Menu` control is intended for navigation but if you don't bind it to a sitemap (probably the most common use), you can use it for whatever you want.  Here's a simple example:

Markup:

```
Select your favorite color:<br />
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server">
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Blue" Value="Blue" />
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Red" Value="Red" />
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Green" Value="Green" />
    </Items>
</asp:Menu>
Your favorite color is:
<asp:Label ID="lblColor" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

Code Behind:

```
Protected Sub Menu1_MenuItemClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.MenuEventArgs) Handles Menu1.MenuItemClick
    lblColor.Text = e.Item.Value
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take one of those standards menu's and replace the links with LinkButtons. Then in your code-behind wire up a click method to each LinkButton's click event.

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact match for a menu, but you might want to take a look at the jQueryUI button [demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#toolbar) for toolbars.